# Do current browsers still validate CRLs in enterprise PKI environments

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-revocation

I know that modern web browsers don't check CRLs for certificates from CAs in the default trust store anymore.
I also know that there are some exceptions for certificate validation when it comes to corporation / enterprise PKIs. For example for the lifetime of a certificate, optional certificate features like issuer policy and so on.

Since I came into an argument if OCSP responder are required in an corporate/enterprise PKI, my question is:

Do current Browsers (Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Safari) in 2023 still check CRLs of webserver and SubCA certificates to determine their certificate validity, if no AIA/OCSP distribution points are specified and the certificates are issued by an corporate/entterprise pki RootCA?

This does not ask the question if the certificates are considered valid. (They are) I ask if the CRL distribution points actual affect the certificate validity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome/Chromium/Edge [can be configured](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#RequireOnlineRevocationChecksForLocalAnchors) to check OCSP and CRL, but they don't by default.  These are options for Webkit based browsers, so the list might be longer than those three.

Firefox [checks OCSP, but not CRLs](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/Revocation_Checking_in_Firefox#Revocation_Processing_for_Intermediate_CA_Certificates). This can't be configured as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Ok, great. From the Mozilla link we can assume that classic CRLs will never be processed. If the PKI operator want to provide certificate revocation, they have to provide an OCSP resolver.